# Xamarin Visual studio cannot detect view in same namespace

Tags: xaml, xamarin

This is my first Xamarin Project and already, I've run into a weird issue.

Fromt he MainPage.xaml, I'm triyng to call the ItemDetailsPage with ItemFetailViewModel as a param.

Upon compilation, VS throws "`The type or namespace name 'ItemDetailsPage' could not be found"`. There is no red underlines.

I've checked that the namaespaces are correct in both the .xaml and .xaml.cs

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace testapp3.Views
public partial.....
{
   Method()
   {
       await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailsPage(new ItemDefailViewModel(item)
   }

}
```

ItemDetailsPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="testapp3.Views.ItemDetailsPage">
</ContentPage>
```

ItemDetailsPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace testapp3.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ItemDetailsPage : ContentPage
    {
        ItemDetailViewModel viewModel;
        public ItemDetailsPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
        public ItemDetailsPage(ItemDetailViewModel item)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this.viewModel = item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I see the xaml and .cs for itemdetailspage ?

Comment: Hi Jon, updated the post!